# Standalone exe: Where on disk to save config files and logs?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

Under Windows, is there a standard convention on where a standalone executable should save logs and config files?

Should it just keep these in the same directory as the executable?

Or is there a special directory for this purpose?
And if there is, how would I get the directory's path?

Comment: There are no real standards, but saving in the same directory as the executable is almost certainly not what you want to do - possibly use the Documents folder. Ideally, you want to give the user the option of specifying where to put the logs etc.

Comment: AppData\YourCompany\YourApp

Comment: Are these files only for use inside the application, or do you expect the user to find and view them with general-purpose tools?

Comment: You can use SHGetKnownFolderPath https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx to get the AppData directory.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Only for the program, they're just for the purpose of remembering a few settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard convention on where a standalone executable should save logs and config files, in Windows?

I would advise keeping config files under
    %APPDATA%\YourCompany\YourApp.

For logs, it depends.

If you are interested in keeping separate logs for every run of the application, I would advise keeping them under:
    %APPDATA%\YourCompany\YourApp\DateStamp\pid
, where DateStamp would be something like 2018-Mar-31 or 2018-03-31

If you are interested in keeping logs in only one file then I would advise using the same location as the config files, 
        %APPDATA%\YourCompany\YourApp.

Comment: Would using this path be okay for all versions of windows >= XP?

Comment: @AnneQuinn, yes.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, that needed to be "you are interested in keeping".